# CGEvent.tapCreate doesn't work for keyboard, but works for mouse events

Tags: swift, macos, input, keyboard

I'm trying to run a Swift app to log keyup/keydown events.
Here is the code:

```
import Foundation
import ApplicationServices

func myCGEventCallback(proxy: CGEventTapProxy, type: CGEventType, event: CGEvent, refcon: UnsafeMutableRawPointer?) -> Unmanaged<CGEvent>? {

    print("type is \(type)")

    if [.keyDown , .keyUp].contains(type) {
        var keyCode = event.getIntegerValueField(.keyboardEventKeycode)
        print("keyCode is \(keyCode)")
        if keyCode == 0 {
            keyCode = 6
        } else if keyCode == 6 {
            keyCode = 0
        }
        event.setIntegerValueField(.keyboardEventKeycode, value: keyCode)
    }
    return Unmanaged.passRetained(event)
}

class MyLogger {

    func start() {
        let trusted = kAXTrustedCheckOptionPrompt.takeUnretainedValue()
        let privOptions = [trusted: true] as CFDictionary
        let accessEnabled = AXIsProcessTrustedWithOptions(privOptions)
        print("accessEnabled is \(accessEnabled)")

//        let eventMask = (1 << CGEventType.keyDown.rawValue) | (1 << CGEventType.keyUp.rawValue)
        guard let eventTap = CGEvent.tapCreate(tap: .cgSessionEventTap,
                                               place: .headInsertEventTap,
                                               options: .defaultTap,
                                               eventsOfInterest: CGEventMask(1 << CGEventType.keyUp.rawValue),
                                              callback: myCGEventCallback,
                                              userInfo: nil) else {
                                                print("failed to create event tap")
                                                exit(1)
        }

        let runLoopSource = CFMachPortCreateRunLoopSource(kCFAllocatorDefault, eventTap, 0)
        CFRunLoopAddSource(CFRunLoopGetCurrent(), runLoopSource, .commonModes)
        CGEvent.tapEnable(tap: eventTap, enable: true)
        CFRunLoopRun()
    }
}
```

If I run it, I receive "accessEnabled is true" and "failed to create event tap"

However, if I replace `CGEventMask(1 << CGEventType.keyUp.rawValue)` with `CGEventMask(1 << CGEventType.mouseMoved.rawValue)`, it works fine and I receive mouseMoved events.

What I have tried to do:

- Added Accessibility and Input Monitoring permissions, tried to check/uncheck multiple times
- Add Sandbox entitlements and set it to NO
- Sign with my developer certificate
- Read almost all stackoverflow related questions

I run it on MacBook Air M1, Mac OS 12.5.1 and Xcode 14.0

Comment: Does it help if you use `.keyDown` and also add the app to *Accessibility* not *Input Monitoring*?

Comment: @Daniel thanks for reply! I found the way to fix it, gonna post my own answer later

Answer (score 0):

This was a strange issue, but the problem is solved.

- Remove the app
- Change the Bundle ID
- Build & run again

Looks like the issue was with registering a permission for a selected bundle id.